# Wicket WebApplication/WebPage circular dependency using spring

Tags: java, spring, wicket, circular-dependency

In my wicket spring based applications, I have this method to inject the spring manager to the `WebApplication` class:

```
private void initManager() {
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
    this.manager = (MyManager) applicationContext.getBean("manager");
}
```

I usually setup the internal error page inside the `init` method of my `WebApplication` class. Sometimes I also mount some bookmarkable pages:

```
public class MyApplication extends WebApplication {

    @Override
    protected void init() {
        IApplicationSettings applicationSettings = getApplicationSettings();
        applicationSettings.setInternalErrorPage(ErrorPage.class);
        mountBookmarkablePage("privacy", PrivacyPage.class);
    }

    //............
}
```

My `WebPage` classes usually depend on my manager class, for instance:

```
public class ErrorPage extends WebPage {

    public ErrorPage() {
        MyApplication application = (MyApplication) getApplication();
        add(new EmailLink(application.getManager().getMailSupport()));
    }
}
```

So, my `WebApplication` class refers to one or more pages, and my pages refer to the `WebApplication` class. Is this a circular dependency? If yes, how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it is not a circular dependency but it is a configuration.

However, I think you can always inject your manager bean to the web page class as well with autowiring.

EDIT:

You may also need to enable spring annotations in applicationContext.xml as well and add some new dependencies if not already in classpath

see applicationContext.xml sample [at this address](http://fmucar.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/vaadin-maven2-add-on-spring/) and your will be pretty much similar except the scan package name. Update those values accordingly.

```
public class ErrorPage extends WebPage {

@Autowired
private MyManager myManager;

//setter getter methods as well
}
```

Comment: Use wicket-spring's @SpringBean instead of @Autowired.

Comment: @fmucar: +1 for your effort, thank you. Unfortunately, I still use spring 2.5 and your linked example doesn't fit so much, but I've understood what you've suggested. The solution is to inject my manager to my base page, I just have to think about my favourite way to do this.

Comment: @martin-g: You're right, I like your @SpringBean solution. If you want, you can add your solution as a new answer.

Comment: It is not introduced in spring3, it also exists in v2.5 but as martin-g suggests, if there is a special annotation for that in wicket, it better to use that one.